# Modifying one JavaScript array using setState() updates a second state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My React App displays a grid of names for selection.  When I select a name it reads a database and shows rows of data applicable to that name. With each row being an object, which is stored as a single array element.
I have two arrays to contain the objects, one is the 'original data' and the other is the 'modified data'. Then I compare these to see if there has been a change to one of the rows before updating the database.
The arrays are defined so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
        detail_data: [],
        old_detail_data: []
    }
}
```

When I select a row a call is made to _handleRowClick():

```
_handleRowClick(i) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        this.getRecord(i, (err, res) => {
            if (!err) {
                let detail = res.body;
                this.setState({
                    name_detail: Object.assign({}, detail),  // Stores details about the name
                    selectedIndex: i
                })
                // Fetch the Career Directions
                this.fetchSingleCareerDirections(this.state.detail.animal_code);  // Gets the rows
            }
        })
    }
}

fetchSingleCareerDirections(animal_code) {
    request.get(`/lookup/career_directions/${animal_code}`, (err, res) => {
        let data = [].concat(res.body);  // row data
        this.setState({
            detail_data: [...data],      // array 1
            old_detail_data: [...data],  // array 2
        });
    });
}
```

At this point all is well and my data is as expected in detail_data and old_detail_data. So I modify one piece of data in one row, in this case clicking a checkbox (for valid career), but any change to row data has the same effect:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox"
        checked={item.valid_career == 'Y' ? true : false}
        style={{ width: 30 }}
        name={"valid_career|" + i}
        onChange={(e) => { this._setTableDetail("valid_career", e.target.checked == true ? 'Y' : 'N', i) }}
    />
</td>
```

Which calls the update routine _setTableDetail() to store a 'Y' or 'N' into the detail_data array:

```
_setTableDetail(name, value, index) {
    let _detail_data = Object.assign([], this.state.detail_data);
    _detail_data[index][name] = value;
    this.setState({ detail_data: _detail_data });
}
```

This updates **this.state.detail_data** as expected. But if I look at **this.state.old_detail_data** the exact change has also been made to that array. Likewise, as a test, if I modify old_detail_data that updates detail_data.
This MUST be happening because the two arrays both reference the same memory space. But I cannot see how that is happening. My setState() routine, as seen above, does this:

```
this.setState({
    detail_data: [...data],
    old_detail_data: [...data],
});
```

Which, to my understanding, uses the spread operator to create a new array in each instance. So how are these two arrays both referencing the same memory space? Is it something to do with me doing the cloning inside the setState() call maybe?

Comment: You are spreading a collection of non-primitives aka objects (your `data` result), and so the new arrays `detail_data` and `old_detail_data` contain the same object references, so any changes to an object in either of those arrays is updating the same object. A simple example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/r890yuao/ Depending on the structure of your `data` objects, you can look into some cloning options, a number of which are on SO. Possibly `detail_data: data.map(d => ({ ...d })` _may_ work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much @Anthony for your comment. You were quite right in where I was going wrong. So although my arrays were unique their contained objects were referencing the same objects in memory.

I modified the code of the fetchSingleCareerDirections() function to resolve the issue:

```
fetchSingleCareerDirections(animal_code) {
    request.get(`/lookup/career_directions/${animal_code}`, (err, res) => {
        let data = [].concat(res.body);
        this.setState({
            detail_data: data.map(row => Object.assign({}, row)),      // array 1
            old_detail_data: data.map(row => Object.assign({}, row)),  // array 2
        });
    });
}
```

The program now works perfectly.

Just one point to note. I am using a slightly older version of JavaScript for which the spread operator didn't work (sadly). But testing this elsewhere beforehand I was able to use Anthony's code, as suggested, which is a better more modern approach:

```
fetchSingleCareerDirections(animal_code) {
    request.get(`/lookup/career_directions/${animal_code}`, (err, res) => {
        let data = [].concat(res.body);
        this.setState({
            detail_data: data.map(row => ({ ...row })),      // spread operator
            old_detail_data: data.map(row => ({ ...row })),  // spread operator
        });
    });
}
```